# How to upper case a string of auto created property in a PHP class like in JavaScript?

Tags: php, class, variables, dynamically-generated, uppercase

I need to transform to uppercase a string setted by dynamic **__set** constructor of my PHP class. Just like JavaScript **.toUpperCase()** function.

Exemple:

```
$myObject = new Post();
$myObject->fooVar = 'Upper Case Test';
$myObject->fooVar->toUpperCase();
echo $myObject->fooVar;
```

Need to output:
*UPPER CASE TEST*

This is my actual class code:

```
class Post {
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Class "'. __CLASS__. '" started!'; // constructor debug
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo 'Class "'. __CLASS__. '" destroyed.'; // constructor debug
    }


    public function __get($varName)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($varName, $this->data))
        {
            //this attribute is not defined!
            $this->data[$varName] = 'ERROR!';
            return $this->data[$varName];
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->data[$varName];
        }
    }

    public function __set($varName, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$varName] = $value;
    }

    public function toUpper($object){
        $object = strtoupper($object);  
        return  $object;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks for all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do it using the syntax in your example code. The variable you are accessing is a string and doesn't have a `toUpperCase` function. If you must use a function format like that, I'd say the best way I can think to do this by adding the `toUpperCase` function to your `Post` class like this.

```
class Post {

    ...

    public function toUpperCase($key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->data) && is_string($this->data[$key])) {
            $this->data[$key] = strtoupper($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
$myObject = new Post();
$myObject->fooVar = 'Upper Case Test';
$myObject->toUpperCase('fooVar');
echo $myObject->fooVar;
```

However, I think something like the following would be better and doesn't require the `toUpperCase` function.

```
if ($myObject->fooVar)
    $myObject->fooVar = strtoupper($myObject->fooVar);
```

I'd recommend modifying your `__get` definition to return false at the very least if the key doesn't exist (an exception might be better, but depends on how you use this class). If you are returning a string, this forces you to do a string comparison to error check which is needless extra code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The purpose of my question is know how to use PHP OO like in JavaScript, with several inline functions changing the object's content.

Example:
`
var test = 'Object';
var concatText = 'in JavaScript ###';
alert(test.concat(" ", concatText).replace('###','123').toUpperCase());
`